# Modifying Joomla html5 module chrome

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to modify the module chrome for the Joomla custom html module. I understand that I can simply overwrite it or create an alternative chrome by creating a modules.php file in my template html folder. However, I have no idea where I can find the code for the existing, standard Joomla chromes so that I can modify them - does anybody know where the standard chrome php/html markup files are located or generated in the file system? Of course I could write it all from scratch in theory but I just want a slight variation to the existing html5 module and I would like to see how it is constructed to learn from it. Anybody got any clues where t can be found in Joomla 3.1? The documentation is sparse on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the system modules.php file that comes with joomla as a starting point for your own module chrome. It is located under the **templates/system/html/modules.php**

For the custom html module overrides:
Copy the default.php file located under the **/modules/mod_custom/tmpl/** directory over to **/templates/yourtemplatename/html/mod_custom/** directory.

Comment: Happy module chroming!